# Different results between xcode and simulator

Tags: swift, xcode

in the picture a part of screenshot with a xcode printed code and the same result on an iPad simulator, can any one tell me why please?

[image: Screenshot]

here is the code

```
 func loadLevel() {
    var clueString = ""
    var solutionString = ""
    var letterBits = [String]()

    if let levelFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "level\(level)", withExtension: ".txt") {
        if let levelContents = try? String(contentsOf: levelFileURL) {
            var lines = levelContents.components(separatedBy: "\n")
            lines.shuffle()

            for (index, line) in lines.enumerated() {
                let parts = line.components(separatedBy: ": ")
                let answer = parts[0]
                let clue = parts[1]

                clueString += "\(index + 1). \(clue)\n"


                let solutionWord = answer.replacingOccurrences(of: "|", with: "")
                solutionString += "\(solutionWord.count) letters\n"
                solutions.append(solutionWord)

                let bits = answer.components(separatedBy: "|")
                letterBits += bits
            }
        }
    }
    print(clueString)
    cluesLable.text = clueString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    answerLable.text = solutionString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    letterButtons.shuffle()

    if letterButtons.count == letterBits.count {
        for i in 0..<letterButtons.count {
            letterButtons[i].setTitle(letterBits[i], for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove labels line limitation in your code or your storyboard.

in code:

```
   @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!{
        didSet {
            self.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        }
    }
```